# Different interface depending on the profile type?

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0

I have C# Windows Form Application. Before launching program I have login page for authentication. It requires login, password with sending to server.
Server returns me access type with token.

Access type can be several types: user, super user, editor.

How depending this to change interface of program? I dont want to make this using hiding elements of interface:

```
if(Auth.type == "Admin"){
   label1.visible = false;
   .....
}
```

Comment: I can only think of a slight improvement on your suggestion.  If you use UserControls - maybe one for each role, then you can dynamically add the relevant ones to the form in the constructor or some initialise method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create separate user controls and load them according to the authentication type or you can create different landing forms for all authentication types.

Comment: What is difference between interfaces of different users?

Comment: Admin has another top, left menu.

Comment: if(Auth.type == "Admin")
{ 
 usercontrolAdmin admin=new usercontrolAdmin();
 this.Controls.Add(admin);
}

When you are using user controls

Comment: if(Auth.type == "Admin")
{ 
 frmAdmin admin=new frmAdmin()
 admin.Show(); //admin.ShowDialog();
}

When you are using forms